# Make a config, that is periodically refreshed by a background thread, easily accessible to the rest of the program

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust by implementing simple use-cases that are common and trivial in other languages. Recently, I decided to prototype a small component for retrieving some "config" from a remote source every X minutes. The local version of config should also be made available to the rest of the program.

This is what I came up with. I'm looking for improvements in my code, especially within the `get_config` method where I had to clone the entire config. Note that a lot of stuff (like error handling and graceful shutdown) has been left out for  brevity.

```
use std::{sync::{Arc, RwLock}, thread::{self, JoinHandle, sleep}, time::Duration};


#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Config {
    // Simplest possible config. 
    pub quote: String
}

struct ConfigProvider {
    refresher: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    config: Arc<RwLock<Config>>
}

impl ConfigProvider {

    pub fn new() -> ConfigProvider {
        let mut provider = ConfigProvider{
            refresher: None,
            config: Arc::new(RwLock::new(Config {quote: "(empty)".to_owned() }))
        };
        let data_ref = Arc::clone(&provider.config);
        let th = thread::spawn(move || ConfigProvider::refresh(data_ref));
        provider.refresher = Some(th);
        provider
    }

    fn get_config(&self) -> Config {
        // Question: How to avoid cloning here, so this method 
        // becomes as cheap as possible ? 
        return self.config.read().unwrap().clone();
    }

    fn refresh(dest: Arc<RwLock<Config>>) {
        loop {
            sleep(Duration::from_secs(5));
            println!("Refreshing quote..");
            let response = reqwest::blocking::get("https://api.quotable.io/random");
            if response.is_err() {
                println!("Error fetching quote: {:?}", response.err().unwrap());
                continue;
            }

            let text = response.unwrap().text();
            if text.is_err() {
                println!("Error reading quote: {:?}", text.err().unwrap());
                continue;
            }

            let quote = text.unwrap();
            {
                let mut config = dest.write().unwrap();
                config.quote = quote;
            }
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let provider = ConfigProvider::new();
    loop {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(3));
        let config = provider.get_config();
        println!("Retrieved quote: {}", config.quote);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change

```rust
config: Arc<RwLock<Config>>

...

fn get_config(&self) -> Config {
```

to

```rust
config: Arc<RwLock<Arc<Config>>>,

...

fn get_config(&self) -> Arc<Config> {
```

This way, while you do still need to `clone()` the value out of the lock, the clone simply consists of incrementing the reference count, not copying all data in the `Config`.

A further refinement of this approach is to use the [`arc-swap`](https://docs.rs/arc-swap) library, which lets you avoid using any locking at all, but update the config by atomically swapping in a new `Arc<Config>` pointer. This has the advantage that the config updater cannot ever cause the config readers to block. In that case, you'd write

```rust
config: ArcSwap<Config>,
```

and the `ArcSwap` type handles all the rest of the functionality.

---

Another thing: Right now, `ConfigProvider` is structured around both updating the config *and* handing it out. Notably, it isn't `Clone`. This may prove inconvenient later, because code which needs the config cannot *own* something that lets it fetch the latest config. I recommend that you explicitly split out the “sending” role from the “receiving” one, [like channels](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/mpsc/) do. Now, in the case of the code you've shown here, there is actually nothing to do but **stop storing the `JoinHandle`**:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct ConfigProvider {
    config: Arc<RwLock<Arc<Config>>>,
}

// or if you take the above advice to use `arc-swap`,
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct ConfigProvider {
    // need an outer Arc to make it shareable by cloning
    config: Arc<ArcSwap<Config>>,
}
```

Now, any code that wants to track the latest config can clone and hang onto a `ConfigProvider` indefinitely; it acts as the *receiving* side of the channel, and the thread acts as the sending side.

Answer (score 2):

Right now the `ConfigProvider` mixes the responsibilities of owning the config, scheduling the updates and also performing the actual updates having to know the config structure. If you want to reuse this tool in another project you'd have to copy-n-paste.

I suggest to restructure the solution and provide the `ConfigProvider` with a generic type parameter that represents the actual config and maybe an update function that can simply update a config instance.

This way the implementation of the actual config and how it receives its values and the scheduling of background updates and keeping it thread-safe is split. Makes it more versatile for the future IMHO.

**Update**: Also I'd avoid `println` all over the place - use [log](https://docs.rs/log/latest/log/) and one of the logging implementations to get message output.